# How can one find subsequent results using MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, reporting, nosql-aggregation

Imagine the following:

```
{
    "user" : "john",
    "type" : "connect",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-02T10:00:00.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "user" : "john",
    "type" : "disconnect",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-02T10:10:00.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "user" : "frank",
    "type" : "connect",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-02T10:05:00.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "user" : "frank",
    "type" : "disconnect",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-02T10:15:00.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "user" : "john",
    "type" : "connect",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-02T10:15:00.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to create an outage-report telling "user john had 5 minutes of downtime". I'm completely in the dark right now, I digged into aggregation aswell as mapReduce but nothing seems to point in the direction where I need it. I could solve it using plain javascript but I want to avoid that since MongoDB is so made for aggregation of those kinds. Maybe I'm just stuck in my head and need to let it rest for some while, but maybe someone has a good solution for me.

So best output would be (I guess):

```
{
    "user" : "john",
    "outage": "5"
}
```

Besides this "optimal" example, there may be cases where disconnects are swallowed by the system when deploying a new server version. Those are about 10 seconds and I'm thinking about leaving them out for the sake of ease.

Comment: And what about frank ? He won't have new connect entry ?

Comment: Sure he could have a new connect entry. Simple user-database scenario but with an outage documentation since my users are sort-of-ap(i/e)s.

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{user:"$user",type:"$type"},created:{$max:"$created"}}},{$sort:{"_id.user":1,"_id.type":-1}},{$group:{_id:"$_id.user","latest_disconnected":{"$first":"$created"},"latest_connected":{$last:"$created"}}},{$project:{outage:{$divide:[{"$subtract": [ "$latest_connected", "$latest_disconnected" ] },60000]}}}])
```

**Output**

{ "_id" : "john", "outage" : 5 }

{ "_id" : "frank", "outage" : -10 }

Here is the details explanation

> This will give you the latest entry of each user for type connected
>   and disconnected

```
{$group:{_id:{user:"$user",type:"$type"},created:{$max:"$created"}}}
```

> Don't forget to sort by user and type, group does not guaranteed of
>   sorted output

```
{$sort:{"_id.user":1,"_id.type":-1}}
```

> As each user will have 2 entry from previous pipeline, so first entry
>   will be for latest disconnect and last(second) entry for latest
>   connect

```
{$group:{_id:"$_id.user","latest_disconnected":{"$first":"$created"},"latest_connected":{$last:"$created"}}}
```

> This is simple mathematics, difference between 2 dates and converted
>   into min

```
{$project:{outage:{$divide:[{"$subtract": [ "$latest_connected", "$latest_disconnected" ] },60000]}}}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: thanks for feedback, will give this a shot tomorrow!

Comment: thanks a lot for your documented help, although it didn't really put out what I was looking for. Maybe I didn't ask clear enough. Anyways I'll close down this question, as my solution was nearhand and is javascript based.

Comment: What you are looking for ?

Comment: I'm looking for a documentation of outage. I now create a report for each user connecting, which makes grouping a lot easier. I can then $sum the outage values (containing seconds) together and make up the time the api was disconnected.

Anyways: Thanks a lot for your help!